# Preventing Page Reload when Using Query Inside Child Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm facing a challenge in my React application where, upon clicking the "Show More" button, the page unexpectedly reloads. This behavior seems to be related to the useGameQuery within the QuestCard component. I would appreciate guidance on how to maintain the desired functionality of showing more quests without triggering a page reload caused by the useGameQuery. Is there an approach I can adopt to avoid this reloading behavior while still utilizing the useGameQuery for individual QuestCard component?

```
const QuestCard: FC<QuestCardProps> = ({ quest, gameId }) => {   
  
  const [{ data, error }] = useGameQuery({ variables: { gameId } });   
  if (!data?.game?.title || error) {
    return null;   
  }

  return (
    <CompletableQuestCard
      quest={quest}
      title={data.game.title}
      logo={data.game.logo}
      badgeImage={data.game.tokens}
      isMainlandingQuestCard={true}
    />); 
};

export const QuestTypeSection: FC<{ title: string; quests: Quest[] }>
= 
  ({   title,   quests, }) => {   
  const isMobileView = useMediaQuery(Breakpoints.mobile);   
  const maxRows = 2;   
  const [displayedRows, setDisplayedRows] = useState(maxRows);

  const handleShowMore = () => {
    setDisplayedRows((prevRows) => prevRows + maxRows);   
  };

  const filteredQuestCard = useMemo(() => {
    return quests.slice(0, displayedRows);   
  }, [quests, displayedRows]);

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        gap: "16px",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      <Texts
        kind={isMobileView ? "tomorrow14" : "tomorrow24"}
        style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}
      >
        {title}
      </Texts>
      <QuestList>
        {filteredQuestCard.map((quest) => (
          <QuestCard quest={quest} gameId={quest.gameId} key={quest.id} />
        ))}
        <Box>
          {quests.length > displayedRows && (
            <button onClick={handleShowMore} type="button">
              <Texts kind={isMobileView ? "GradientTextSmall" : "GradientText"}>
                Show More
              </Texts>
            </button>
          )}
        </Box>
      </QuestList>
    </Box>   
  ); 
};
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in DevTools/Console? `react-query` cannot reload the page on its own, it's designed to handle data loading and caching and that's it. Ideas to try: 1) add `event` to arguments of `handleShowMore` and call `event.preventDefault()` there(however `type="button"` should be already enough) 2) verify that no exception happens during rendering new `QuestCard` in case you have ErrorBoundary in the project(then "catch render-time exception and restore the state" _may_ look as "page reload")